# Accessibility for UINavigationController and UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

I'm improving the **accessibilty** of my iOS project and am using an UINavigationController.
My UINavigationItem has two buttons, the left one is "Cancel".

By default, the cancel buttons gets selected when showing the view.
So the first thing a user hears is "Cancel".

What I really want is that the **title** should be selected and spoken, and the
cancel button should **not be selected**.

**Questions:**

1. Is this how it should be, and what could be the reason for this?
2. Has anyone successfully unselected the button and instead selected the title?

Thanks,
Claes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple's UIAccessibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> **UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification** - Posted by an application when the layout of a screen changes, such as when an element appears or disappears. This notification includes a parameter, which is either an NSString object that VoiceOver speaks or an accessibility element that VoiceOver moves to.

So you can do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,title);
}
```

You should replace "title" in the above code with the actual Accessibility element you want to be selected and spoken.

You can also use **UIAccessibilityScreenChanged** instead of **UIAccessibilityLayoutChanged** *"when a new view appears that comprises a major portion of the screen"*.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried exactly that, and even zeroing the selected bit of the left button:s trait bit field. No luck. This seems to be a default behaviour that is difficult to change.

Comment: It is the default behavior but not difficult to change. I am using the code I posted with no problems in similar circumstances (navigationcontroller as well). It doesn't matter what the trait of the left button is, the notification is forcing to switch focus to the element you pass as argument). I simply typed in "title" above, but you have to change this to the correct element in your app. For example, it could be "self.title" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, user1459524!

It worked fine. A bit curious about why it has to be done as late as in viewDidAppear.
But never mind that. Whatever works.

Thanks again.